# How to utilize more than 512MB of RAM in your android app?

Tags: android, performance, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

I am working on an app that will be exclusively used on a limited set of devices, all of which have 6GB of RAM. Currently my app is misbehaving as it touches the 512MB mark. I want to be able to **utilize more RAM (~1GB)** because I know the devices allocated to users are for one purpose only and that is to use this app so it is **not an issue** that this app is taking majority of the device RAM.(*Google play services are not available in this device and there is no browser either*)

The app is doing a wide variety of heavy operations simultaneously while also continuously updating UI so it is **bound to cross the 512MB**. I have so far managed to keep it all under 480MB but with the plan of upcoming features that I have start implementing today, I think it is inevitable that the app will have to use more RAM.

Please advise on how to utilize more RAM. I have not been able to find any good answer to this

I have tried setting android:largeHeap="true" but that doesn't seem to do to the trick.
Also checked out this relevant post about this but it hasn't provided the best solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

> Please advise on how to utilize more RAM

You could:

- Split your app into multiple processes. Each process' VM can use up to the heap limit. You will be limited to using inter-process communication (IPC) between the two processes, such as bound services.
- Move some of your heavy-RAM logic to C/C++. Native memory allocations (`malloc()` and things built atop it) are not subject to the heap limit of the VM.
- Focus more on optimizing your memory use, such that you can fit within your heap limit.

> I know the devices allocated to users are for one purpose only and that is to use this app so it is not an issue that this app is taking majority of the device RAM

If this device has custom firmware, you could raise the heap limit in the firmware.

Comment: I checked your answer yesterday and so far it has been my best lead so thanks for that. I haven't actually done anything to increase the RAM usage yet instead I have been trying to be more efficient with memory usage but there were no memory leaks and there are just way too many things running at once in the app so there's only so 'efficient' I can be with memory. I will let you know what I did to take care of memory once I do it.